# How to make XSD choice unambiguous (Unique Particle Attribution - UPA)?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have seen other old questions similar to this but none with actual solutions. I have the following schema:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:element name="p1">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="el1" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="el2" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="el2" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="el1" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="el1" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="el2" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

As a result I get the following error:

> el1 and el1 (or elements from their substitution group) violate
>   "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this schema,
>   ambiguity would be created for those two particles.

I know that this means that the schema is ambiguous in some way, but I don't see how. As I understand it the schema above should mean *Either an `el1` followed by an `el2`, an `el2` followed by an `el1`, an `el1`, or an `el2`.* If that is indeed the case then I don't see how a situation would come about where it is not clear which of these 3 situations we are in.

If you have an alternative that does **exactly** what I described should happen above, I am open to it.

Comment: The thing about UPA is not so much that your schema must be unambiguous, but that it must be unambiguous *without lookahead*. As soon as you see an el1 element, you have to know which branch of the choice to take without looking to see what comes next. With your model, you can't do that.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks so much, that definitely improves my understanding. Ideally the right answer would be a combination of your comment and kjhughes answer.

Comment: Well,  when I said that my solution ***makes it unambiguous which choice applies as soon as the first el1 or el2 element is parsed***, I implied *without lookahead*.   I've now added it explicitly, but note that if you found the original form to be ambiguous, you'll now need to look ahead to the last two words in the sentence to resolve the ambiguity.  :-)

Comment: I think my confusion just stemmed from the fact that i wasn't aware that lookahead was even a factor in determining ambiguity. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible in this case to rearrange the `xsd:choice` possibilities into a logically equivalent form that makes it unambiguous which choice applies as soon as the first `el1` or `el2` element is parsed *without lookahead*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="p1">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="el1" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="el2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="el2" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="el1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```